# How to run UDP sockets from the same SRC and DEST port (c++)

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I can't figure out how to send and receive multiple messages on the same source and destination ports. My server has to keep listening all the time, but sending is intermittent (can happen at random times) So technically sending and receiving should be on separate threads. Please help. Here is my code:

```
    int main()
{
    std::thread UDPServerControlThread (KNXUDPControlServer,60000); //start server to listen on port 60000
    sendOneWayUDPMSG(SOMEDATA,DATASIZE); //I need this to send from the source port 60000 to the destination port 3671
    //wait some random time, do some processing...
    sendOneWayUDPMSG(MOREDATA,DATASIZE);
///more processing...
}
```

And here are the functions mentioned above:

```
    void UDPControlServer(int serverPort)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

        int s, slen = sizeof

(si_other) , recv_len;
    char buf[512];

    //create a UDP socket
    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        DEBUG_MSG("CREATING UDP SOCKET FAILED" << endl);
    }

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
    //si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //bind socket to port
    if( ::bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
        DEBUG_MSG("BINDING SOCKET TO PORT FAILED" << endl);
    }

    //keep listening for data
    while(1)
    {
        //printf("*CONTROL-SERVER Waiting for data...");
        fflush(stdout);

        if ((recv_len = ::recvfrom(s, buf, 512, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, (socklen_t*)&slen)) == -1)
        {
            DEBUG_MSG("*CONTROL-SERVER RECEIVING FROM SOCKET FAILED" << endl);
        }

    }
    }
```

And this Function:

```
void sendOneWayUDPMSG(unsigned char * messagePayload, int messageSize)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_in;
    int s, slen_in=sizeof(si_in);
    //char buf[512];

    if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        DEBUG_MSG("FAILED TO CREATE SOCKET" << endl);
    }

    memset((char *) &si_in, 0, sizeof(si_in));
    si_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_in.sin_port=htons(3671); // port

    if (::inet_aton(KNXIPInterfaceAddress.c_str() , &si_in.sin_addr) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //send the message
    if (sendto(s, messagePayload, messageSize , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_in, slen_in)==-1)
    {
        DEBUG_MSG("SEND TO SOCKET FAILED" << endl);
    }

    close(s);
}
```

To summarize, my code basically listens on port 60000 and sends data to the external server on its local port of 3671. But those packets that are sent are sent from random source ports. I need them to be sent on port 60000 as well.

Comment: Well of course it's from a random port, you create a new `socket` in `sendOneWayUDPMSG` for every message. This socket has a random UDP port assigned it to it.

Answer (score 0):

> My server has to keep listening all the time, but sending is intermittent (can happen at random times) So technically sending and receiving should be on separate threads.

Not exactly.  You should be multiplexing your I/O using `select`, `poll`, or possibly even `epoll`.

If you want to have the same source port on outgoing packets as the port that you're receiving packets, just re-use the socket descriptor you get here in your `UDPControlServer` function...

```
 if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
{
    DEBUG_MSG("CREATING UDP SOCKET FAILED" << endl);
}
```

in your `sendOneWayUDPMSG` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you be able to point me to a really good tutorial? I keep finding different links online and non of them really teach me what I want.

Comment: @HadiEsper The man pages for most of the functions are online (including [`poll`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)).